# Generic route prefix + specific route in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have a system where, before specifying the data you want to access, you need to provide the company you are accessing from, to check for authorization.

For example, to get products, materials and users:

**GET company/123123/product**

**GET company/123123/material**

**GET company/123123/user**

When creating the express routes in node JS, I'm using the prefix "company/:id" in all my routes declarations:

app.get("**/company/:id**/product", callbackProduct);

app.get("**/company/:id**/material", callbackMaterial);

app.get("**/company/:id**/user", callbackUser);

The question is, is there any way to generalize this 'company' part of the route, in a way that I don't need to re-write it in all routes?

For example:

**app.*something*("/company/id:/*", genericCallback);**

app.get("/product", callbackProduct);

app.get("/material", callbackMaterial);

app.get("/user", callbackUser);

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to use express.Router.
In an `company.routes.js` you would write something like that.

```
const express = require("express");
const CompanyRouter = express.Router();

CompanyRouter.get("/:id/product", callbackProduct);
CompanyRouter.get("/:id/material", callbackMaterial);
CompanyRouter.get("/:id/user", callbackUser);

module.exports = CompanyRouter;
```

And in your `server.js` file you would do the following.

```
const express = require("express");
const CompanyRouter = require("./path/to/CompanyRouter.js")

const app = express();
app.use("/company", CompanyRouter);
app.listen(3000);
```